# How can I fix this series of errors?

Tags: java, arraylist, binary-search

I am trying to write a program that tests out binary search for an ArrayList, but I keep getting errors that I do not know how to fix.

This is my code for the binary search:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BinarySearchTest  {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        ArrayList<Integer> searchable = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
              searchable.add(i);
        int someNumber = 7;
        int index = binarySearch(searchable, someNumber, 0, searchable.size()));
        System.out.println(someNumber + ((index == -1) ? " is not in the array" : (" is at index " + index)));
    }

    public static boolean binarySearch(ArrayList<Integer> searchable, int check, int lo, int hi)
    {
        int first = 0;
        int last = searchable.size() - 1;
        int mid;
        while(first <= last)
        {
            mid = first + (last - first) / 2;
            if(check == searchable.get(i).getTotal())
            {
                return true;
            }else if(searchable.compareTo(searchable.get(i)) < 0)
            {
                last = mid - 1;
            }else
            {
                first - mid + 1;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The errors that are being returned are:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<Integer>
    The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<Integer>

    at BinarySearchTest.binarySearch(BinarySearchTest.java:24)
    at BinarySearchTest.main(BinarySearchTest.java:13)
```

I think it has something to do with my binarySearch method needing to be adjusted to work with an ArrayList rather than just regular arrays.

Comment: The errors you show and the code you show do not match. Have you changed the code?

Comment: But in the main, one problem you're having is that you're trying to run code that won't compile. Your seeing multiple compilation errors in code suggests that your coding process is wrong. Instead of writing out all your code and then trying to compile and run, you should first build a "skeleton" program, make sure it compiles, and then add lines to this program, one at a time, and either use an IDE which warns you of compilation errors, or compile frequently and fix all errors before adding more lines.